# Sampling a Parameter Space with a Neural Network versus other Methods

Tags: neural-networks, sampling, optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, conv-neural-network

I have heard a lot about neural networks as an approach to sampling a large parameter space in aim of finding the space of model parameters that match a dataset. I've done some research online, but almost all articles or writings on neural networks are not welcoming to a person without some experience with it.

I would like to know what a neural network is, and more specifically, how it primarily differs from other traditional approaches to sampling a parameter space such as MCMC. What is the largest difference between MCMC and a convolutional neural network? What about the difference between Nested Sampling and a convolutional neural network?

Comment: a neural network is a statistical model like linear/polynomial regression. it doesn't have any direct relationship to sampling.  You can use MCMC to estimate the parameters of. neural network in a Bayesian framework, just as with linear regression.

Comment: you're probably referring to the "lottery ticket hypothesis", which might be a fruitful search keyword

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "neural networks as an approach to sampling a large parameter space in aim of finding the space of model parameters that match a dataset"? The discovery of parameters that "match" a dataset sounds like the process of estimating a model (very standard procedure for a neural network) and this is an *optimization* task, not a sampling task. But perhaps you have a more specialized usage in mind. Can you [edit] to clarify what you mean? Including a citation to a paper about "sampling a parameter space with a neural network" will be very helpful.